# How to install requests in python 3.7 on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.7

I have trying to install requests in python 3.7 on Mac. I already have python 2.7 installed. 
I have read all the previous questions related to this and none of them could solve the issue.

```
 pip3.7 install requests
bash: pip3.7: command not found
python3.7 -m pip install requests
/usr/local/bin/python3.7: No module named pip
```

I am not able to understand the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no “pip3.7”, just “pip3”. Try this: 
pip3 install requests

Comment: That probably means you don’t have python 3 installed.

Comment: When I run python3 --version, I get Python 3.7.6. I would think Python3 is installed right?

Comment: Then you might need: brew postinstall python3

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading python3 via brew fixed this issue for me.

```
brew upgrade python3
```

And then:

```
pip3 install requests
```

Answer (score 0):

for updating python to the last version do this:
first go to python.org and download the latest version of python then run it and do the installation then in the terminal write this =>

```
python3 --version
```

it should show the latest version

for installing requests do this:

```
sudo apt install python3-requests
```